# Add input form inside a table

Tags: php

So inside my table before `tbody` tag, I inserted a `form` inside `tbody`. However while submitting its form, the url is getting `btnchange.php?qty=1` instead of `btnchange.php?prod_id=cartno`.

**shopcart.php**

```
<?php // start
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE cartuser = '$userid' and cartpend='IN CART'");
   $stmt->execute();

      if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
      {
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
        extract($row); //end ?>


<form method="get" action="btnchange.php?prod_id=<?php echo $row['cartno'] ?>">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['cartno']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['cartname']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['cartprice']; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="<?php echo $row['cartqty']; ?>"></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['cartsub']; ?></td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary"><?php echo $row['cartpend']; ?></span></td>
      <td><button type="submit" name="submit">Submit Quantity</button></b>
      <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="?delete_id=<?php echo $row['cartno']; ?>" title="click for delete" onclick="return confirm('Sure to Delete?')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</form>
```

This is my `btnchange.php` code, this is what i used to get the `prod_id` code and the `qty` input from `shopcart.php`.

**btnchange.php**

```
//get prod id
if(isset($_GET['prod_id']) && !empty($_GET['prod_id']))
  {
          $prod_code = $_GET['prod_id'];
          $newqty = $_GET['qty'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put query parameters in the `action` attribute. You need to use a hidden `input` instead:

```
<?php // start
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE cartuser = '$userid' and cartpend='IN CART'");
   $stmt->execute();

                          if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
                          {
                            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                            {
                            extract($row); //end ?>
                      <form method="get" action="btnchange.php">
                      <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" value="<?php echo $row['cartno']; ?>">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $row['cartno']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['cartname']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['cartprice']; ?></td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="<?php echo $row['cartqty']; ?>"></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['cartsub']; ?></td>
                          <td><span class="label label-primary"><?php echo $row['cartpend']; ?></span></td>
                          <td><button type="submit" name="submit">Submit Quantity</button></b>
                          <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="?delete_id=<?php echo $row['cartno']; ?>" title="click for delete" onclick="return confirm('Sure to Delete?')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Remove</a></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                      </form>
```